# Webview download/cache video

Tags: android, caching, video, webview

I have a webview in android that goes to website that has a video tag in it. What would be the best way to either download the video or cache it so that it won't download every time it's being played. Couldn't find anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

Download the video when you load it first time, and store it in your app's data folder. After that intercept the video url request in your webview and stream the video from local.

```
 @Override
 public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
```

//Here check whether /*request.getUrl().toString()*/ is video url, if Yes, then

Get the locally saved video and convert it as inputstream and return as follows,

```
return new WebResourceResponse(getMimeType(request.getUrl().toString()), "UTF-8", 200, "OK", responseHeaders, inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example using [Okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

In this example it downloads a file and also shows a progress bar to the user with the progress of the file being downloaded.

```
class VideoDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "http://myamazingvideo.mp4";                        
        Call call = client.newCall(new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build());

        try {
            Response response = call.execute();
            if (response.code() == 200 || response.code() == 201) {

                Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = response.body().byteStream();

                    byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 4];
                    long downloaded = 0;
                    long target = response.body().contentLength();
                    mediaFile = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), "mySuperVideo.mp4");
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);

                    publishProgress(0L, target);
                    while (true) {
                        int readed = inputStream.read(buff);

                        if (readed == -1) {
                            break;
                        }
                        output.write(buff, 0, readed);
                        //write buff
                        downloaded += readed;
                        publishProgress(downloaded, target);
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();

                    return downloaded == target;
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                    return false;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setMax(values[1].intValue());
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0].intValue());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (mediaFile != null && mediaFile.exists()) {
            playVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `WebView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can play video by yourself with help of `MediaPlayer` and use `AndroidVideoCache` for caching.